# Double integral over fractional part of Einstein-like velocity sum $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \{\frac{u+v}{1-u v}\} \,dudv$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, fractional-part

Looking for more interesting and complicated examples of this type of problem I propose this one inspired by Einstein's addition theorem for relativistic velocities

$$i =\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \{\frac{u+v}{1-u v}\} \,dudv = 0.502331527971...\tag{1}$$

Here $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.

In fact, Einsteins formula has a plus sign in the denominator, and you can start with that exmple for warming up.

The question is the usual one: is there a closed expression for $i$?

Here is the graph of integrand of $i$

[image]

I haven't solved the problem yet, but I took a first step substituting integration variables so that one of the new variables is the expression under the fractional part. That is $u\to r, \frac{u+v}{1-u v}\to s$, or inverted  $u\to r, v\to \frac{s-r}{1+r s}$. The Jacobi determinant is $\frac{1+r^2}{(1+r s)^2}$. The range of the new variables follows from $0<v<1$ giving $0<\frac{s-r}{1+r s}<1$ leading to $r<s<\frac{1+r}{1-r}$. And, trivially, $0<r<1$.

Our integral then becomes

$$i_1 = \int_{0}^{1}\,dr \int_{r}^{\frac{1+r}{1-r}} \,ds \frac{1+r^2}{(1+r s)^2} \{s\}\tag{2}$$

Compared to many other cases the $s$-integral has two variable boundaries (instead of, say, (r,$\infty$)). This makes the decomposition into discrete intervals more challenging.

I stop here for letting us jointly try to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried substituting $u = \tan(x)$, $v = \tan(y)$? $\frac{u+v}{1-uv} = \tan(x+y)$ then.

Comment: @ Rumpelstiltskin Now that you are asking I remember this substitution (in the hyperbolic form) from the University time which is long ago. In the meantime, Jack D'Aurizio has obvioulsly made much progress with this change of variables.

Answer (score 5):

A natural substitution is $u=\tan\theta, v=\tan\varphi$, bringing the given integral into the following form:
$$ I = \iint_{(0,\pi/4)^2}\frac{\{\tan(\theta+\varphi)\}}{\cos^2\theta\cos^2\varphi}\,d\theta\,d\varphi $$
By setting $\theta+\varphi=u$ and $\theta-\varphi=v$ and exploiting symmetry we get
$$ I = 4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\min(u,\pi/2-u)}\frac{\{\tan u\}}{(\cos u+\cos v)^2}   \,dv\,du $$
or
$$ I = \underbrace{4 \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{u}\frac{\{\tan u\}}{(\cos u+\cos v)^2}   \,dv\,du}_{2-\pi+2\log 2}+4\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{u}\frac{\{\cot u\}}{(\sin u+\cos v)^2}\,dv\,du $$
or
$$ I = 2-\pi+2\log(2)+4\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{z\left\{\frac{1}{z}\right\}}{(1+z^2 w^2)\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2 w^2+1}}\right)^2}\,dw\,dz$$
or
$$ I = 2-\pi+2\log(2)+4\int_{1}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left\{z\right\}}{z(z^2+w^2)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{w^2+z^2}}\right)^2}\,dw\,dz$$
or

$$ I = 2-\pi+2\log(2)+4\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{(1+z^2)(z+(1+z)\log(1+z^2)-(1+z)\log(1+z))}{z^5(z+1)}\{z\}\,dz$$
or
$$ I = 2-\pi+2\log(2)+\small{4\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{(1+z^2)(z+(1+z)\log(1+z^2)-(1+z)\log(1+z))}{z^5(z+1)}(z-n)\,dz}$$
or
$$ I = 2-\pi+2\log(2)+4\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n $$
with $a_n$, depending on $n,\arctan(n),\arctan(n+1),\log(n+1),\log(n^2+1)$, is a positive contribution which behaves like $\frac{\log(n+1)}{2n^3}$ as $n\to +\infty$. The last series is a "moral analogue" of $-\frac{1}{2}\zeta'(3)$.

Comment: always impressive to see what tricks you have up your sleeve

Comment: Very well done. What is your numerical result?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: summing up to the $100$th term of the last series my version of Mathematica returns a $0.502089$. So we may agree the value of the wanted integral is very close to one half.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio This is slightly smaller than the rough result Mathematica gave me directly (see OP). Other question: did you attempt to pursue the calculation of $\sum_a(n)$ further?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: I noticed there is some cancellation due to telescopic terms, but ultimately we still have to manage series like $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n+1)}{n^3}$ or $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n^2+1)}{n^3}$ which do not have a nice closed form.